image background turns black on python pillow
ive been trying to make a chess bot using pillow and discord.py, but when i try to paste a png photo with no background it replace the background to black
ps: you need to write pip install pillow in the terminal/shell to use the code
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
img = Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(410, 410), color="white")

black_rook = Image.open("black_rook.png")

currect_image = black_rook

img.paste(currect_image, (50, 50))

img.save("test.jpg")


the rook image file
board image
if you want to check this its currectly on replit, my account name is shomshom37 and the project is "Game_hub_bot1.0", heres a link: https://replit.com/@shomshom375573
i expected the image to be pasted without the background, insted it added the background to the picture

also if you cant access my replit account that means i moved to vscode

Your code is incomplete and not runnable - please read [mcve] then  click [edit] and update it. Thank you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

i fixed it, it should work now

You need to use the alpha channel of the image as the mask when pasting, like this:
img.paste(currect_image, (50, 50), currect_image)

Otherwise all the pixels of the background image are affected, rather than only those where the pasted image is opaque.

also do u know why i cant upvote your answer?

Maybe you didn't quite have enough points. You should have some more now. Glad it worked for you.
